# Is there a safer way to Cycle Through Post Data in Craft

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

Currently, I am doing this.

```
$responses = array(
        "E" => 0,
        "I" => 0);

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (strlen($value) == 1) {
        ++$responses[$value];
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use craft()->requests for this? I tried

```
foreach (craft()->request->getPost() as $key => $value) {
    if (strlen($value) == 1) {
        ++$responses[$value];
    }
}
```

But this did not seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't consider it as good practice to do what you want, there are good reasons why something like this is not possible by default and why all functions to get all parameters are private.

A better way is to send your parameters inside an array and fetch this or you can create an array of all possible parameters and loop it

```php
$secureParameters = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
$request = Craft::$app->getRequest();
$values = [];
foreach($secureParameters as $key){
    $values[$key] = $request->getBodyParam($key);
}
```

If you really don't care about receiving unexpected parameters and raising exceptions you can also loop your `$_POST` directly `foreach($_POST as $key => $v){` and fetch the `$request->getBodyParam($key)` at least